# XMLHttpRequest POST data size

Tags: post, size, xmlhttprequest

Is there a size limit to a XHR POST request? I am using the POST method for saving textdata into MySQL using PHP script and the data is cut off. Firebug sends me the following message:

```
... Firebug request size limit has been reached by Firebug. ...
```

This is my code for sending the data:

```
function makeXHR(recordData)
{
    xmlhttp = createXHR();

    var body = "q=" + encodeURIComponent(recordData);

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "insertRowData.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", body.length);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
        {
            //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            alert("Records were saved successfully!");
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(body);

}
```

The only solution I can think of is splitting the data and making a queue of XHR requests but I don't like it. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

XHR Post has no size limit, but you're sending data to PHP which has a size limit ;)
Create the following php-file and open it in a browser:

```
<?php phinfo(); ?>
```

Now search for the variable "post_max_size", this variable limits the maximum data that can be sent to PHP (but it can be changed in the php.ini)

Comment: Hi, my initial value for "post_max_size" was 8M and I increased it to 80M and restarted the server. This is not the problem I think because the data will never reach 8M in the first place ...

Comment: Only because Firebug has problems with this filesize does not mean it doesn't work ;)
Have you checked if the js-code works when the firebug-console is not active?

Comment: I have a suspicion where the problem is. I use a XHR GET method for retrieving the data and GET is limited:

function retrieveRows()
{
xmlhttp = createXHR();
 
xmlhttp.open("GET","retrieveRowData.php", false); 
 
try
{
 xmlhttp.send(null);
}
catch(err)
{
 errormessage="There was an error on this page.\n\n";
 errormessage+="Error description: " + err.description + .\n\n";
  errormessage+="Click OK to continue.\n\n";
  alert(errormessage); 
 }
 
 return xmlhttp.responseText;
}