# Error parse XML XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

Hi all I have to make a connection with an external server to request data by an XMLHTTPRequest.
I have make a page but when I send the request return me this error:

> Error!
>   Parser : Request XML ( oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException: Start
>   of root element expected. Error No:4001)

I don't know if is a problem of parsing or character or a something else.
This is my script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var req = null ;
var firsttime = false;

function sendRequest(){
    var urlStr="http://mylink.it";
    var xmlString="";
    xmlString="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><BOOKING type='COR' lang='it-IT' returnURLNeed='no' returnURL='http://' AGENTCODE='XXXX' AGENTPASSWORD='YYYY' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='http://link/schema/CountryRequestV6Snd.xsd'><DATA ALL_COUNTRIES='YES'/></BOOKING>";
    createHTTPRequestObject();
    var resp = getResponseText(urlStr+"?"+xmlString,null);

}

function createHTTPRequestObject(){
    req=null ;
    var pXmlreq = false ;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        pXmlreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try{
            pXmlreq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e1) {
            try{
                pXmlreq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } 
            catch (e2) {
            }
        }
    }
    req = pXmlreq ;
}



function getResponseText(action,query,method,async,contenttype){
    if(method==null){
        method="POST";
    }
    if(async==null){
        async="true";
    }
    if(contenttype==null){
        contenttype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    }
    console.log("open");
    req.onreadystatechange= function() { 
        if (req.readyState == 1) {
            if (firsttime==false){
                firsttime = true;
                req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", contenttype);
                if(query){
                    console.log("send request");
                    req.send(query);
                }else{
                    console.log("send request2");
                    req.send();
                }
            }
       }
       if (req.readyState >= 4) {
            var serverResponse = req.responseText;
            console.log(serverResponse);
       }
    }
    req.open(method,action, async);
}
</script>
```

My post request
POST

`/trlink/link1/trlink?<?xml%20version='1.0'%20encoding='UTF-8'?><BOOKING%20type='COR'%20lang='it-IT'%20returnURLNeed='no'%20returnURL='http://'%20AGENTCODE='XXX'%20AGENTPASSWORD='YYY'%20xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'%20xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='http://link/CountryRequestV6Snd.xsd'><DATA%20ALL_COUNTRIES='YES'/></BOOKING> HTTP/1.1`

Comment: The server is returning the error. We can't see what it is doing to try to parse the data you are submitting.

Comment: I know but would be a method to understand the problem to solve it

Comment: 1. Understand what input the service is expecting. 2. See if what you are giving it conforms to that. (We have no way to know 1).

Comment: I have update my question with the code in post @Quentin

Comment: You're still only showing us the input you are sending. We still have no way to know what the server you are sending it to is expecting.

Comment: I have tried I hope that support of this server contact me... pfff bad documentation on it..

Comment: The way you create the URL looks really wrong. I bet you want to send the XML string as the POST HTTP request-body. See the many related resources how that works, e.g. [XMLHttpRequest POST data size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069342/xmlhttprequest-post-data-size)